# Stars at night without long shutter speed lines

Tags: nikon, long-exposure, stars, night-photography, nikon-d50

I've seen breathtaking milky way photos that have no trail/streaks which of course I always get when shooting my DSLR at 30 seconds or longer - I can't find a clear answer that doesn't include using editing software to layer multiple images into one.
How do you guys do it?  And is it possible with a Nikon D50 & kit lens 18-55
Tia?

Comment: It is achievable with your kit, though a little harder as the camera is a little old and the lens not so fast (buying a cheap 50/1.8 might help). The most important thing is to find an area to shoot from with very dark skies - light pollution from urban areas is a huge problem. If you find a good spot you could even see it with your own eyes. Get a fast wide lens, get yourself in a very remote location - I've taken milky ways in single shots on just a tripod - location was key

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/14696/65832

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "Rule of 600" in astrophotography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30263/what-is-the-rule-of-600-in-astrophotography)

Comment: You can search the web for the *500 rule* which is also sometimes referred to as the *600 rule* and also the more complex *NFP rule*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid star trails without an expensive tracking mount?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8684/how-can-i-avoid-star-trails-without-an-expensive-tracking-mount)

Comment: Also related: [This answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/98718/15871) to [What is a tracked and un-tracked image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98717/15871)

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use stacking software. But as @qrk points out in their answer, such software doesn't have to be expensive or difficult to use. Sequator is a good suggestion.

Comment: I would rather advise you to get a faster/better wide angle lens and to try and see for yourself the kind of results you can get before purchasing a tracking mount. There are great lenses, even some old and quite cheap manual lenses with hard infinity focus stop which is great for astrophotography. You would have more viable options with a full frame body though.

Answer (score 2):

You would typically use an equatorial tracking mount. This is a motorized mount that tracks the apparent movement of the sky. The inexpensive systems run about USD 400. You can get an idea of what is offered at the [BH Photo](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?q=star%20tracker&sts=ma) web site. Another technique is piggy backing the camera to a telescope with a tracking mount which is what I do when others/organizations allow me to do so. Typically, you set up the mount so it is approximately aligned (about 0.5° off) with the Pole Star.

The D50 coupled with the 18-55 kit lens isn't the best system for astro photos, but you can have fun with it if you have a tracking mount. For good results, you will need to take multiple images and stack them using a program like [Sequator](https://sites.google.com/view/sequator/). There are better and more confusing astro stacking programs out there, but Sequator is relatively easy to use. Stacking will allow you to reduce camera image noise. Also, the features in an astro stacking program allow you to remove other artifacts which detract from the image.